# How to route a not SEF url? angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to create a new route for my angular 2 application... The url is the callback from the spotify API after user grant permissions to my app

this is an example of the call back:

> http://localhost:8080/callback?code=AQBIIG2Klo0RzZf94a2Ag_gcn_JIrwv2d8N2ABVyCMwxmf1rmLFzq9HsUR08v8MY4ZiQ0Gl6-hWLGqiwtYGADt0TdbKYaD_Z9VKJMFvE97TVs0IsfYfs7ALZpsuVHaa-urSzzFmvZu4PdtyFp7WeMqtrDVDHie6k6NoeuG0LUfUxwmtG7TCfhUZvxY0c0V9bAVEGHiO1Izo_4WgOfNs78IYj1ZvclM-7j-zHAGgLEvwtjyX25vxKng&state=Q8L4joXNk3M8UVQt

I tried this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'callback/code/:code/state/:state', component: CallbackComponent }
];
```

And this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'callback?code=:code&state=:state', component: CallbackComponent }
];
```

But I cant get the routing works... 
I always get this message:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'callback' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'callback'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 differentiates between route parameters(required) and query parameters(optional), in your example, `code` and `state` would be query parameters and they shouldn't need to be explicitly defined in the Route's `path` property but passed as query params.

So you would have a Route defined like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'callback', component: CallbackComponent }
];
```

And you can call it in a template like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/callback', { code: 'SOME_CODE', state: 'SOME_STATE' }]">Component Link</a>
```

Or programmatically like so:

```
this.router.navigate(['/callback', { code: 'SOME_CODE', state: 'SOME_STATE' }]);
```

You should also know that Angular doesn't use `?` or `&` to separate query parameters instead it uses `;`, called matrix URL notation.

More info in the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-required-or-optional

Hope it helps! fellow Glober :B

PD: I'm assuming you're using the latest router version, it changes a lot with each version.

EDIT: Added another way to navigate to a route with query params.

Comment: thanks...
The problem is that Spotify callback URL send the query parameters separated with & and ?

How can I read them in the callback controller?
I tried     
this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(+params['code']);
             console.log(+params['state']);

        });

But doesnt work... I think because te code and state parameters were not defined in the Routes

Comment: Does your CallbackComponent need to use the value of `code` and `status`, or do you just need to navigate the user to the URL the spotify endpoint gives you?, 'cause if you need the values from that URL that comes with '?' and '&' you're just gonna have to strip them from the string, and then pass them as query parameters to the CallbackComponent, you can't access them using route.params 'cause Angular doesn't recognize them as query parameters, for getting the param values out of an URL you can use something like [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/)